# Could the acts_as_tenant Rails gem suffer from race conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, race-condition

The acts_as_tenant gem sets the tenant based on subdomain upon each request.
If a user hits a page on a different tenant at the perfect moment... is it possible for another person's action to save to an incorrect tenant?

Comment: Depends entirely on how it stores what the current tenant. Perhaps you could extract the relevant bit of code from the gem

Answer (score 0):

AaT uses RequestStore (https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store?source=c) to store the current tenant at the middleware level.

As far as i'm aware this makes AaT immune to the type of race conditions you describe.